# How do I test a camera in the iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Is there any way to test the iPhone camera in the simulator without having to deploy on a device? This seems awfully tedious.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

There are a number of device specific features that you have to test on the device, but it's no harder than using the simulator. Just build a debug target for the device and leave it attached to the computer.

List of actions that require an actual device:

- the actual phone
- the camera
- the accelerometer
- real GPS data
- the compass
- vibration
- push notifications...

Comment: That kinda sucks, what if you need to test on an earlier version of the OS set in your deployment target, guess you'd be screwed then.

Comment: Downgrade? That's the reason Xcode includes a one-click restore.

Comment: Here are instructions how to downgrade your device: http://www.iclarified.com/31004/how-to-downgrade-from-ios-7-beta-to-ios-6

Comment: Weren't push notifications a device-only feature, too?

Comment: Yay for downgrading to test the camera functionality...? there's gotta be a better answer than "roll back"...

Comment: my camera don't work in my ipod touch ios 10.2.1, would be nice if I can test the functionality with the simulator

Comment: I don't own an ios device. If I want to test on a real device I need to ask to someone.. That sucks..

Comment: wtf, not everyone has an iOS device just because they're developing for iOS

Comment: 10 years on, we still don't have this functionality.

Comment: Question: "Can I use the camera on the IOS sim and not a physical device"
Answer: "Use a physical device"
Outcome: "Thanks for that"

Comment: RN developers have android or ios actual device quite often. So the Q is ok to me. What is not ok is the fact that in 2021 there's still no any option to emulate a camera neither a virtual scene (e.g. for testing QR codes scanning) in ios emumator out-of-the-box. Sorry guys but comparing to android emulator, the ios one looks fast and memory-friendly but quite poor in it's dev  tools and options

Answer (score 9):

I needed to test some custom overlays for photos.  The overlays needed to be adjusted based on the size/resolution of the image.

I approached this in a way that was similar to the suggestion from Stefan, I decided to code up a "dummy" camera response.

When the simulator is running I execute this dummy code instead of the standard "captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection".

In this dummy code, I build up a "black photo" of the necessary resolution and then send it through the pipelined to be treated like a normal photo.  Essentially providing the feel of a very fast camera.

```
CGSize sz = UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) ? CGSizeMake(2448, 3264) : CGSizeMake(3264, 2448);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sz, YES, 1);
[[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, sz.width, sz.height));
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

The image above is equivalent to a 8MP photos that most of the current day devices send out.  Obviously to test other resolutions you would change the size.

Comment: Smart @Craig - I've done something similar ( not so smart I guess ) in a recent project, but used a picture stored in resources. This way it is possible to automate screenshots with fastlane to send on iTunesConnect

Answer (score 1):

Nope (unless they've added a way to do it in 3.2, haven't checked yet).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, with macOS 13+ (maybe macOS 12) and Xcode 14+, is to run the iPhone app via "My Mac (Designed for iPhone)" Xcode target.

[image: My Mac (Designed for iPhone)]

The ["Capturing and Saving a Photo"](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/sample-apps/capturingphotos-captureandsave) Swift Playground provides iOS sample code which use the live macOS camera.

_Note: An arm64 Mac can run "My Mac (Designed for iPhone)" directly. However, An x86_64 with need use "Mac (Mac Catalyst)" to use the live camera with iOS-based API calls.

Comment: This is a clever approach! I even found an extra layout glitch on my app which only showed up when it rendered it for the Mac. One wonders why they don't use that same code in the emulator...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a replacement view to use in debug mode. It implements the same API and makes the same delegate callbacks. In my case I made it return a random image from my test set. Pretty trivial to write.

Comment: And, you could make it to return an image from the iSight Camera :)

Answer (score 0):

A common reason  for the need of accessing the camera is to make screenshots for the AppStore.

Since the camera is not available in the simulator, a good trick ( the only one I know ) is to resize your view at the size you need, just the time to take the screenshots. You will crop them later.

Sure, you need to have the device with the bigger screen available.

The iPad is perfect to test layouts and make snapshots for all devices.
Screenshots for iPhone6+ will have to be stretched a little ( scaled by 1,078125 - Not a big deal… )

*Good link to a iOS Devices resolutions quick ref : http://www.iosres.com/*

---

Edit : In a recent project, where a custom camera view controller is used, I have replaced the AVPreview by an UIImageView in a target that I only use to run in the simulator. This way I can automate screenshots for iTunesConnect upload. Note that camera control buttons are not in an overlay, but in a view over the camera preview.

The @Craig answer below describes another method that I found quite smart - It also works with camera overlay, contrarily to mine.

Comment: That's the point of the question... There is no camera in the simulator.

Comment: Why would you need a camera to take screenshots?

Comment: Why would you need to take screenshots of the camera you mean? To upload screenshots of your camera application in action on the Store, at different screen sizes.