# WKWebView crashes when loaded html includes <input> tag with "capture" attribute

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, camera, wkwebview

In my iOS (Swift) application I am using `WKWebView` to load a website.

The website includes the following input tag

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="user"/>
```

When visiting the site (example [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tiivik/pen/ExXpKEB)) on iOS Safari directly and clicking on `Choose File`, the user facing (selfie) native camera is correctly launched.

When I load the same URL in WKWebView

```
var webView: WKWebView!
webView.load(URLRequest(url: "https://codepen.io/tiivik/pen/ExXpKEB"))
```

... and build an app to a physical device, clicking on the `Choose File` button prompts for native user-facing selfie camera view, working as expected.

Info.plist includes keys for

```
NSCameraUsageDescription
NSMicrophoneUsageDescription
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
```

**The issue**

When the application is tested on simulator, clicking `Choose File -> Photo Library` causes a fatal crash:

```
Example-iOS-Swift[4945:406420] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Source type must be UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera'
```

[image: ios simulator]

Removing capture="user" from the input tag would help avoid the crash, however, for the application, it's important to immediately initialise the selfie camera whenever the button is pressed, hence that's not an option (the site is visited also directly from various devices/browsers.

I've tried, on the web/javascript side to use `navigator.mediaDevices` to disable the button if there are no devices available, however, it seems that `mediaDevices` are provided even in the iOS simulator even when there's no physical user-facing camera available.

Is there a way to avoid the crash when using the iOS simulator while capture="user" is present in the input tag?

Comment: simulator doesn't really have a camera capability (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168484/how-do-i-test-a-camera-in-the-iphone-simulator for example). And simulator is not a real environment user will be running your app on, so why bother to disable anything?
Are you worried that apple will see the crash on app submission?

Comment: Thanks! In this case, currently, the best option I would have is to tell developers working with that Swift project (it's an open-source project) that "do not click this button, it will crash the app". I hope there's a way to gracefully handle that.

Comment: What I usually do, is have a `#if !targetEnvironment(simulator)` condition and get UI to display something else (e.g. static picture) instead of camera. In your case it's more tricky, but still you can have a `#if !targetEnvironment(simulator)` condition, and under it run JavaScript to remove `capture="user"` from the page.