# React Native QRCode Scanner test in IOS Simulator

Tags: react-native

Im working on react native qr code scanner. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qrcode-scanner

I just want to ask if it's possible to test the scanning in IOS Simulator? Currently the camera is not opening for me.

And if it's not possible i'm thinking of doing a remote debugging into a real device. That as of the moment i can't connect with a real device.

Does have any other way to test a camera on development side?

I'm new to react native or any android development this is my first time so any help would be great. Thank you all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I test a camera in the iPhone simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168484/how-do-i-test-a-camera-in-the-iphone-simulator)

Answer (score 4):

**There is no way to scan a QR code without the camera**.

As the iOS simulator doesn't provide some native functionalities, one of them is camera usage.

So, We cannot test QR code scans.